# React Loading Overlay implementation on a <button> click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement react-loading-overlay on a button when it's clicked. This is to help show the back end is authenticating and provide the user feedback that something is happening. I'm unclear on the button how to Activate the loading spinner when clicked, and not have it loading spinner when it's idle. The main issue is I don't understand how to define "active" when the button is clicked.

```
  <Button onClick={handleSign} color="primary">
           <LoadingOverlay
              
              active={What do I use?}
                        spinner
                        text='Loading your content...'
                    >
                    Authenticate
                </LoadingOverlay>
   </Button>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay

Comment: The `active` attribute [based on the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay#props-hammer_and_wrench): *active (boolean) - default: true - whether the loader is visible*.

Comment: Right, I was trying to figure out how to show the loader as active when clicked, and not when it's idle.

Comment: @MrPeachyPenguin could you please share codesandbox link? I couldn't set it up as it was giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

The 'active' value is just a true or false.
It is true if you want it to be spinning
Here is an example using functions and hooks where you can toggle it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import LoadingOverlay from "react-loading-overlay";

export default function App() {
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue", height: "500px" }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setLoading(!loading)} color="primary">
        <LoadingOverlay active={loading} spinner text="Loading your content...">
          Authenticate
        </LoadingOverlay>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `handleSign` update a state value (let's say `active`) to `true` and when you receive response from the backend, update that state (`active`) to `false`

then in the component use that state value:

```
<LoadingOverlay
     active={active}
     ...
>
...
</LoadingOverlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.
You need to set `active` props `true` once you press `sign in` button.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

const handleSignIn = (event) => {
  setLoading(true)
}

...

render() {
  return (
    <LoadingOverlay
     active={loading}
     ...
    >
  )
}
```

Maybe you should have to set `loading` to `false` once signing in succeed or failed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like...

```
const state = {processing: false}
```

then, inside your "handleSign", you can do:

```
this.setState({processing: true})
```

finally, inside your button, you can call that state:

```
 active={this.state.processing}
```